# Compactification in String Theory

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, string-theory

It seems to me that the idea of compactification in String theory is related to the concepts of Compactification and Quotient topology in topology theory. How compactification in String theory can be precisely defined in topological terms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What physicists call a "[compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(physics))" is what mathematicians call a [fiber bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle) with compact fibers. It's somewhat related to quotient topologies in the sense that the projection from the total space to the base is a quotient map; but fiber bundles are much more specialized than quotient spaces.

Comment: Thank you! Could you suggest a reference to read more about the compactification in String Theory in the language of fiber bundles?

Comment: @htr: Unfortunately, I can't. My suggestion is to do a Google Books search with terms like "string theory fiber bundle" and see if any of the books look promising.